# jQuery validate and jqTransform issue

Tags: jquery, validation, jqtransform

I'm having an issue getting checkboxes, radio buttons and selects that have been styled with jqTransform to validate with the jQuery validate plugin.

Has anybody had any experience with this? Is this something I can do with the `addMethod` function?

Here is the link to the form I'm trying to validate :

http://www.kriskrosdemo.com/index.cfm/submit-spring-offers/

Answer (score 2):

That page throws an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqTransform'`.

Regardless, the problem is going to be that jqTransform hides the real checkboxes, radios, etc and replaces them with styled divs and what not.  jQuery Validate by default only validates *visible* things.  This can be fixed by adding an option to your jQuery Validate initialization:

```
$('#myform').validate({
  ignore:'',
  //your options
});
```

The default for that ignore option is `:hidden`, so setting it to `''` ought to fix your issue!